# footcite in a picture,not in the list of figures

Tags: citing

I need to write a footcite of a picture that I have not created, I use this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Images/em_study.JPG}
    \caption{Comparison electric machines\footcite{sourcefigure}}
    \label{fig:Comparison electric machines2}
\end{figure}
```

If I do like that the cire appears in the list of figures and I would like a results like this:[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional argument to the `\caption`. `\caption[<list entry>]{<float entry>}`

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Images/em_study.JPG}
    \caption[Comparison electric machines]{Comparison electric machines\footcite{sourcefigure}}
    \label{fig:Comparison electric machines2}
\end{figure}
```

By the way, in general it is not a good idea to use the `[H]` position; it destroys the the ability to float and can result in a really bad output with often much blank space.

Comment: Hi thanks, but with this option it only deletes the cite in the list of figures, but is not included in the foot of the page

Comment: @PabloNavarro You haven't provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile. Where is `footcite` defined? We have no access to your graphic file --- use something else (just A FIGURE as the contents will do instead of `\includegraphics...`)